# ¿Diferencia al asignar una variable char con memcpy() o directamente dentro de un struct en c++?

Tags: c++, struct

¿Cual es la diferencia entre utilizar memcpy() o directamente un puntero para declarar la variable nombre dentro del struct persona en este codigo?

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct persona{
    char *nombre;
    //char nombre[20];
    int edad;
}persona;

int main(){
    persona persona1;
    persona1.nombre = "juan"; //con puntero *
    //memcpy(persona1.nombre, "juan", 7); //sin puntero
    persona1.edad = 20;
    
    std::cout<<persona1.nombre<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<persona1.edad<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Conozco que internamente un array es un puntero, pero al momento de realizar con puntero me da warning

```
[Warning] deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
```

en contraste al realizar con memcpy y con nombre[20] no me da ningun warning, ¿A que se refiere el warning?

Comment: `char* nombre` es un puntero que no le apunta a nada. La
forma correcta de hacerlo es como lo tienes en tu comentario
(`char nombre[20];`). Y no uses `memcpy` usa `strcpy`.
Ademas, veo que estas en C++, asi que no tienes ningun motivo
para hacerlo asi. 1) No tienes que hacer el `typedef struct
...`, solo con el `struct` te basta. 2) No uses `char[]`,
usa `std::string`.

Comment: Ojo también que cuando la asignas "con puntero" estás asignando la referencia a un espacio de memoria constante en stack, el cual existe únicamente dentro del stackframe de la función, por lo que si se usa afuera de la función puede producir una violación de segmento. Por otro lado, `memcpy` (o `strcpy`) no inicializa el valor del puntero, solo copia de uno a otro, por lo que se puede producir comportamiento no esperado al estar trabajando con un espacio de memoria no inicializado. Ahí habría que usar alguna función `*alloc`. Mejor usa C++ como dice Pablochaches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para conocer la diferencia debemos empezar por aclarar conceptos. En C++ todo tiene un tipo, incluidos los literales de texto. Así pues el literal `"juan"` tiene como tipo `const char[5]` que es una formación<sup>1</sup> constante de cinco caracteres. Son cinco caracteres por las cuatro letras mas el carácter de finalización de cadena y es constante porque es un literal. Cuando escribes esta instrucción:

```
persona1.nombre = "juan";
```

Siendo `char *` el tipo de `persona1.nombre`, el tipo `const char[5]` se convierte implícitamente a puntero a cadena de caracteres (`const char *`) y **normalmente [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) prohíbe explícitamente apuntar a memoria de sólo lectura (`const`) con punteros de lectura-escritura (que no están marcados como `const`)** pero en este caso hace la vista gorda y muestra una alarma por mantener una compatibilidad con [c](/questions/tagged/c)<sup>2</sup>. Lo que está haciendo esa instrucción es apuntar con un puntero al inicio del literal `"juan"`, así que la variable asignada es un puntero (aunque sea del tipo incorrecto).

Si generamos un código de ejemplo y examinamos su ensamblador, vemos que el compilador tan sólo hace eso, una asignación:

```
persona f1()
{
    persona p;
    p.nombre = "juan";
    return p;
}
```

```
.LC0:
        .string "juan"
f1():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Después de la operación, tendrás dos punteros apuntando al mismo sitio y una sola copia de los datos:

```
const char literal[5] ___ 
                         \_______ { 'j', 'u', 'a', 'n', '\0' };
persona1.nombre _________/
```

Si por el contrario hacemos la llamada a `memcpy` vemos que el compilador hace, efectivamente eso, una llamada a función:

```
persona f2()
{
    persona p;
    memcpy(p.nombre, "juan", 5);
    return p;
}
```

```
.LC0:
        .string "juan"
f2():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        lea     rax, [rbp-8]
        mov     edx, 5
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    memcpy
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        leave
        ret
```

Después de la operación tendrás dos punteros, apuntando a sitios distintos pero con una copia de los datos:

```
const char literal[5] --> { 'j', 'u', 'a', 'n', '\0' };
persona1.nombre --> { 'j', 'u', 'a', 'n', '\0' };
```

Por cierto, al contrario de lo que dice tu comentario (`//sin puntero`), llamar a `memcpy` también usa punteros, el puntero a la memoria de destino y el puntero a la memoria de origen; pero además como no has reservado espacio para copiar los datos en la memoria de destino, tu programa puede fallar en tiempo de ejecución.

---

Una vez explicadas estas diferencias, te aconsejo que no uses formaciones de caracteres para guardar texto, en C++ se usa el objeto `std::string`, que es más seguro y fácil de usar:

```
typedef struct persona{
    std::string nombre;
//  ~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- Más seguro y más fácil de usar que una formación de caracteres
    int edad;
}persona;
```

También hay que tener en cuenta que en C++ las estructuras son tipos por derecho propio, así que no necesitan una definición de tipo (`type` `def`inition) para ser tratadas como tal:

```
struct persona {
//     ~~~~~~~ <-- No necesita typedef
    std::string nombre;
    int edad;
};
```

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocido como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

<sup>2</sup>En C el tipo de los literales de carácter no incluye `const`.